# Cannot get spark worker to work in standalone mode

Tags: localhost, apache-spark

I have just started dabbling with Spark, and I ran the start-all.sh command and submitted a job, which worked just fine. So then I moved on to trying to edit the config. I went ahead and changed SPARK_WORKER_CORES in spark-env.sh to 2, but now my job get stuck on this line `INFO AkkaUtils: Connecting to HeartbeatReceiver: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.104.75:9001/user/HeartbeatReceiver`

If I comment my change in the env file, all works well again. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Appreciate any inputs!

EDIT: spark-env.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This file is sourced when running various Spark programs.
# Copy it as spark-env.sh and edit that to configure Spark for your site.
#export SPARK_MASTER_IP="Amits-MacBook-Pro.local"
#SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES="2"
#export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY="1500m"
SPARK_WORKER_CORES=2
#SPARK_WORKER_PORT="9000"
#export SPARK_LOCAL_IP="127.0.0.1"
 #Options read when launching programs locally with 
# ./bin/run-example or ./bin/spark-submit
# - HADOOP_CONF_DIR, to point Spark towards Hadoop configuration files
# - SPARK_LOCAL_IP, to set the IP address Spark binds to on this node
# - SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS, to set the public dns name of the driver program
# - SPARK_CLASSPATH, default classpath entries to append

# Options read by executors and drivers running inside the cluster
# - SPARK_LOCAL_IP, to set the IP address Spark binds to on this node
# - SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS, to set the public DNS name of the driver program
# - SPARK_CLASSPATH, default classpath entries to append
# - SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS, storage directories to use on this node for shuffle and RDD data
# - MESOS_NATIVE_LIBRARY, to point to your libmesos.so if you use Mesos

# Options read in YARN client mode
# - HADOOP_CONF_DIR, to point Spark towards Hadoop configuration files
# - SPARK_EXECUTOR_INSTANCES, Number of workers to start (Default: 2)
# - SPARK_EXECUTOR_CORES, Number of cores for the workers (Default: 1).
# - SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY, Memory per Worker (e.g. 1000M, 2G) (Default: 1G)
# - SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY, Memory for Master (e.g. 1000M, 2G) (Default: 512 Mb)
# - SPARK_YARN_APP_NAME, The name of your application (Default: Spark)
# - SPARK_YARN_QUEUE, The hadoop queue to use for allocation requests (Default: ‘default’)
# - SPARK_YARN_DIST_FILES, Comma separated list of files to be distributed with the job.
# - SPARK_YARN_DIST_ARCHIVES, Comma separated list of archives to be distributed with the job.

# Options for the daemons used in the standalone deploy mode
# - SPARK_MASTER_IP, to bind the master to a different IP address or hostname
# - SPARK_MASTER_PORT / SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT, to use non-default ports for the master
# - SPARK_MASTER_OPTS, to set config properties only for the master (e.g. "-Dx=y")
# - SPARK_WORKER_CORES, to set the number of cores to use on this machine
# - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY, to set how much total memory workers have to give executors (e.g. 1000m, 2g)
# - SPARK_WORKER_PORT / SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT, to use non-default ports for the worker
# - SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES, to set the number of worker processes per node
# - SPARK_WORKER_DIR, to set the working directory of worker processes
# - SPARK_WORKER_OPTS, to set config properties only for the worker (e.g. "-Dx=y")
# - SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS, to set config properties only for the history server (e.g. "-Dx=y")
# - SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS, to set config properties for all daemons (e.g. "-Dx=y")
# - SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS, to set the public dns name of the master or workers

# Generic options for the daemons used in the standalone deploy mode
# - SPARK_CONF_DIR      Alternate conf dir. (Default: ${SPARK_HOME}/conf)
# - SPARK_LOG_DIR       Where log files are stored.  (Default: ${SPARK_HOME}/logs)
# - SPARK_PID_DIR       Where the pid file is stored. (Default: /tmp)
# - SPARK_IDENT_STRING  A string representing this instance of spark. (Default: $USER)
# - SPARK_NICENESS      The scheduling priority for daemons. (Default: 0)
```

Comment: It seems strange to me that setting a value to SPARK_WORKER_CORES might break the configuration. It could be as simple as a typo. Could you please append your `spark-env.sh` in the question?

Comment: @MikelUrkia have added the conf file. I also tried running just a master, and then running 2 slaves by giving it the master url. This is also giving me the same results.

Comment: One more thing that I have figured out is, that when I running a master and slave on the same node with default config, everything works ok, but if I change anything in the config, it breaks. Now, if I run a slave with default config from a different node, it works again. Starting a slave on the master node along with the second slave, again with default config, causes both workers to get stuck

Comment: You might want to try this: `- SPARK_WORKER_CORES="2"`

Comment: @MikelUrkia tried that as well. Didn't help